# Override Getter/Setter with Custom Attribute

Tags: c#

We have a custom ConfigurationManager library that serializes/deserializes a config.json file into an ExpandoObject.

Would it be possible to create a custom attribute that overrides the Getter/Setter of these properties to abstract this ExpandoObject?

Ideally I would be able to use the Attribute like this:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
class Configureable : System.Attribute
{
    public string Default { get; set; }
    public bool IsEncrypted { get; set; }
}


class Test
{
    [Configureable(Default = "0",IsEncrypted = false)]
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
}
```

When I set the value of the decorated property I want to auto-magically update the value of the ExpandoObject, which would then in turn force an update be written to my config.json file.

When I access the value of the decorated property I want the getter to actually return the value of the underlying ExpandoObject. I can do this by manually having the developer modify the getter/setter. I was wondering if I could also do this with code inside of the attribute.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *"To abstract this ExpandoObject"*? Could you please elaborate on what you would exactly expect to happen once a property is decorated?

Comment: Types and Propertiies have no awareness of the Attributes which adorn them.  Attributes are compiled into the assembly and you'd have to use Reflection to access them.  (And vice-versa: Attributes do not know what Types or props they decorate).  So not much chance of an Attribute overriding anything all by itself.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I have clarified my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `http://doc.postsharp.net/location-interception`

That seems to do exactly what I want.

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property)]
    [Serializable]
    class Configureable : LocationInterceptionAspect 
    {
        public string Default { get; set; }
        public bool IsEncrypted { get; set; }

        public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            base.OnGetValue(args);
            if (args.Value == null)
            {

            }
        }

        public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
        {
            //base.OnSetValue(args);
        }
    }


    class Test
    {
        [Configureable(Default = "0",IsEncrypted = false)]
        public string MyValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Its called `PostSharp`, and its gonna cost you. Consider looking at OSS under the title `Aspect Oriented Programming `

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - "Can I use PostSharp Express for commercial products?

Yes. You can build commercial products using PostSharp Express and redistribute them. However, Express Edition only contains a limited sub"

Comment: Yes, of course you have an express edition, which is limited. There are alot of OSS out there which are similar

Answer (score 1):

`ExpandoObject` is a dictionary with object syntax. It is useful only in simple scenarios. If you need complex logic, use `DynamicObject` intead. Override its `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` methods to replicate functionality of `ExpandoObject`, then customize logic of these methods in the way you want.

It's not clear what your requirements are though. If you have a class which holds properties, what is the point of having dynamic objects?

Comment: Im not sure this actually answers the OP's question. I'm assuming he knows what an `ExpandoObject` is.